# how to use two instances of ng2-file-uploader in the same page on ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I create ionic 4 project and use ng2-file-uploader, in case I use one instance of ng2-file-uploader is work good.

but when I use two instances of it, there is problem: the onFileselected emitter fires for the second instance when I select file in first one.

in HTML

```
<fileUploader
                    #fileUploader
                    id="{{item.FieldName}}"
                    [autoUpload]="false"
                    [extraData]="{label:item.Caption}"
                    class="file-uploader-container"
                    url="{{userData.ServiceURL}}Attachments?UserID={{userData.UserID}}&FormID={{navParams.formID}}&IDValue={{navParams.IDValue}}"
                    token="{{userData.Token}}"
                    uploadLabel="{{'uploadSelectImageButtonLabel' | translate}}"
                    [value]="item.AttachPath"
                    accept="image/jpeg,image/png,"
                    (onFileSelected)="onImageChange($event,item.FieldName)"
                  ></fileUploader>
```

in component.ts

```
  constructor(private ch: ChangeDetectorRef) {
this.fileUploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem: FileItem) => {
  if (this.fileUploader.queue.length > 1 && this.multiple === false) {
    this.fileUploader.removeFromQueue(this.fileUploader.queue[0]);
  }
  this.onFileSelected.emit(fileItem, this._id);
  this.markAsChanged();
};
this.fileUploader.onErrorItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
  //Handle
  this.onError.emit({ item, response, status, headers });
};
this.fileUploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
  //Handle
  this.onSuccess.emit({ item, response, status, headers });
};
this.fileUploader.onCompleteAll = () => {
  //Handle
  this.ch.detectChanges();
  this.onCompleteAll.emit();
};
```

}

in page.ts

```
  onImageChange(fileItem, field_name) {
const { isAutoGPS } = this.navParams;
let file: File = fileItem._file;
let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
  this.defaultValue[field_name] = myReader.result;
  this.formgroup.get(field_name).setValue(file.name);
};
myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

}

any solutions plz?

thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is it clear now?